# Copying animation using copy transform on IK pole/target bones

Tags: animation, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I have a very specific question. I am trying to compare a human MOCAP animation to the same animation, but where the interlying bones are controlled by IK. So I would use the same end-effector and start-of-chain locations, but let the IK determine the positions of the interlying bones: knees (upper leg bone), elbows (upper arm/lower arm) and middle spine bones. To start I tested it out on only the leg movement.

For this, I have two of the same character in the field. One with the original animation and one with the animations of the aforementioned bones removed. I then added the leg pole/target bones to both characters as normal, but kept them parented on only the first character (MOCAP character) so they would move with the animation. I then applied copy transform (local with parent) on the target/pole bone and applied IK on the lower leg bone of the IK character, so that when I play the animation on the MOCAP character, the leg of the IK character moves with it, see figure.

[image: Blender setup]

Now my goal is to capture this new movement of the IK character in an animation. However, recording a pose within a frame only works if you move the bones in pose-mode by hand, but not when I play the animation on the MOCAP char and therefore make the IK character move. Does anyone here have an idea how I can record the movement of those target/pole bones?

I also tried to record the movement of the pole/target bones on the MOCAP character, but there I have the same issue. And even if I can get that to record, there is the problem that the pole/target bones do not move or rotate with respect to the surrounding bones/ in local space, but only in global space. So there wouldn't really be anything to record.

I hope whoever is reading this is still with me at this point. Does anyone have a clever idea how I can make an existing animation IK-based and record the new animation?

P.S. The end goal is to quantify the angle differences between the MOCAP character and the IK character. That is why I need to record that. (Finding the positions of the bones or the angle values is the next problem I'm facing lol)

Comment: You can use a "bake action" operation with visual keying to write the effects of constraints onto keyframes for those bones; usually, you'll also want to enable "clear constraints."  If you would like the transform of a bone in a different space than it exists, you can make another bone in the desired space and copy transforms, world->world, then bake that bone.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just looked up some videos and I'm gonna try it out. Looks like it is what I was looking for ;)